# Node and revision id

Tags: nodes

I am working with a company setting up a drupal website. I am responsible for entering our product information into the drupal tables. I am having difficulty getting a straight answer/an answer that makes sense as to what the values for `nid` and `vid` should be in the `drupal_node` and `drupal_node_revision` tables should be. I am being told by our vendor that the values for `nid` and `vid` need to be the same (ie 27 and 27) but that doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the `vid` just start at 0 or 1 and increment up from there. Isn't it simply what the node table uses to read the current version from the revision table.

I know very little about drupal so I may be wrong but their answers aren't making sense to me. And as the `nid` is automatically incremented in the table, I have no way of knowing what the `nid` value is until after the insert. So I would have to read the value and run an update statement, which seems really sloppy.

Comment: Are you trying to "write" nodes directly to the database? The node id (nid) and revision id (vid) should be handled by the Entity API when you create nodes using entity_create() or the UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you begin to add nodes and never edit them, like you would do when migrating data to a new Drupal installation, then the nid and vid would increment at the same pace, and would *happen* to be the same. After first edit though, assuming you have revisioning on, the new vid would be what ever is the next available number for *all* revisions.

Comment: So, do they have to be the same at the beginning? For my example each node corresponds to a specific product. Should the revision id's start at 1 or the corresponding node id?

Comment: I was just describing what happens when you create nodes with node_save or in the UI, and then edit them. You really don't need to worry about vid when using node_save or UI. For entering your data one good way is to create nodes with node_save function. There are also modules for that, for example Migrate. Writing sql for creating nodes directly to the database is the hardest way, I think.